# Android WifiManager scanresults giving inconsistant data after gingerbread?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

i have an android application that continuesly scan the available wifi accesspoints for their signal strength. I´m using the WifiManager to do just that.

This has been working fine until a week ago when we upgraded the phones to gingerbread. Now it seems "SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION" gets triggered before every acesspoint was scanned. There are always a few missing that apear in the next scan, where others are missing again.

Is this some kind of bug in the new android version or is there some way to get every acesspoint in range instead of just a few different ones every time?

btw this happens on the samsung galaxy s1&s2 and the acer android tablet, so its not just the device

thx for any help you can give us

Comment: try filling out a bug on, looks like minor device-depend problem. http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I developed for Android. Actually WifiManager has been flimsy since Froyo (at which point rapid scans would break the system), and the issues seem to be bugs in the Android system.

Depending on what you're doing with your data, there are some workarounds. For example, we logged Wifi data for research purposes, so whenever we got scan data we double-checked them before inserting them in the database.

Hope this helped!
N.S.

Comment: yeah we are doing something similar, except we need as many values as possible since we are trying to locate android devices based on the RSSI data. this means rescanning a few times is not really feasible

Comment: Sadly I don't think there are workarounds... I would file a bug report.